# Ask for the presence of all specified values?

Tags: sparql

I have exactly these triples in GraphDB:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

<http://example.com/greeting>
  a <http://example.com/word> ;
  rdfs:label "hello" .
```

I want to know if there is a thing in my triplestore with the label "hello" ***and another*** with the label "goodbye"

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

ASK
WHERE
  { VALUES ?l { "goodbye" "hello" }
    ?s  a                     :thing ;
        rdfs:label            ?l
  }
```

I am being told that yes, this is **`true`**, *as if it is saying **at least one** of those are true.*  But I want to know if **all** of those patterns are true.

Can I do that in a `SPARQL ASK`?

I also tried the following but got the same (unwanted) result:

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

ASK
WHERE
{ VALUES (?l) { ("goodbye") ("hello") }
    ?s  a                     :thing ;
        rdfs:label            ?l
  }
```

Sanity check:  the answer to this `ASK` is **`false`**

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

ASK
WHERE
{ VALUES (?l) { ("goodbye") }
    ?s  a                     :thing ;
        rdfs:label            ?l
  }
```

Comment: You can't use `VALUES` here as it is more or less a shortcut for `UNION`. The pattern to use here is a simple intersection, i.e. two triple patterns `?s rdfs:label "goodbye" . ?s rdfs:label "hello" .` or to be more concise: `?s rdfs:label "goodbye", "hello" .`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks. That makes sense. I was just discussing this with a colleague and maybe I was unclear. I don't expect the same ?s to have both labels "hello" and "goodbye". I want to know if there are two different `:thing` instances, one with the label "hello" and another with the label "goodbye"

Comment: Ah sorry, then I misunderstood the problem for sure. Indeed `VALUES` is still not working for this kind of query as it wouldn't ensure matching individuals to be different from each other for each value. The obvious way would be `?s1 rdfs:label "goodbye" . ?s2 rdfs:label "hello" . FILTER(?s1 != ?s2)` , but I guess you're looking for a more compact solution, right?  I'm not aware of any, but what I can say is that `VALUES` would work like the logical disjunction in `ASK` queries.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a sub-`SELECT` query that returns the number of distinct matching subjects `?s` and in the outer `ASK` query check whether the number is equal to the number of values. I'm sure you know what I mean :D

Comment: `ASK {  FILTER(?cnt = 2) {SELECT (count(distinct ?s) as ?cnt) {VALUES ?l { "goodbye" "hello" }
    ?s  a                     :thing ;
        rdfs:label            ?l} } }`   (untested)

Comment: You could even add another sub-`SELECT` for the `VALUES` clause only to get the number of values and use that in the `FILTER` - some kind of overkill for sure :D

Comment: 5 new comments since midnight EDT!  I'll try these ideas sometime today.  Thanks.  I especially like the ASK wrapped around a count aggregation form a select.  I can do that as a Boolean RDF4J query.  Previously, I would have done the count, retrieved the one binding set form the one statement and then compared that to an expected count in Sacala.

Comment: `ask.. filter... select... count... values` definitely does the job, even when specifying a named graph between the `ask` and the `filter`

Comment: Good to hear. You should provide an answer once you found the most satisfying solution for your task. Cheers

Comment: @AKSW here you go!

Comment: @MarkMiller i see you already accepted an answer, but have a look at the one i just posted.  I think it might be a bit simpler for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than asking "are all of these present", ask "is any of these not present" (and then negate the result either I've your application or with another "filter not exists":

```
ask {
  values ?label { "hello" "goodbye" }
  filter not exists {
    ?s a :thing ; rdfs:label ?word
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I updated my "answer" with your syntax applied to my real data.

Answer (score 2):

My group is developing tools to convert tabular data about hospital records into RDF triples and then perform various cleanups and aggregations.

- I have started this "answer" by writing out an illustration of this workflow with sample data.
- Working implementations of the suggestions from @Joshua Taylor and @AKSW's are at the bottom.

The tabular data is first converted into "shortcut triples", which instantiate a minimal number of classes and link all literal values to those classes, even if the literal values are really "more about" something else.

**So tabular data like this:**

```
+-------+------------+----------+----------+
| EncID |  EncDate   | DiagCode | CodeType |
+-------+------------+----------+----------+
|   102 | 12/05/2015 | J44.9    | ICD-10   |
|   103 | 11/25/2015 | 602.9    | ICD-9    |
|   102 | 12/05/2015 | I50.9    | ICD-10   |
+-------+------------+----------+----------+
```

**First becomes triples like this (ignoring the EncDates and CodeTypes.)**

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  obo:  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>
PREFIX  xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

INSERT DATA {
  GRAPH turbo:encounters_from_karma {
    turbo:5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1 rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 .
    turbo:5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1 turbo:ScEnc2DiagCode "J44.9" .
    turbo:5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1 turbo:ScEnc2DiagCodeRegText "ICD-10" .
    turbo:5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1 turbo:ScEnc2EncID "102" .

    turbo:81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7 rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 .
    turbo:81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7 turbo:ScEnc2DiagCode "I50.9" .
    turbo:81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7 turbo:ScEnc2DiagCodeRegText "ICD-10" .
    turbo:81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7 turbo:ScEnc2EncID "102" .

    turbo:820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 .
    turbo:820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f turbo:ScEnc2DiagCode "602.9" .
    turbo:820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f turbo:ScEnc2DiagCodeRegText "ICD-9" .
    turbo:820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f turbo:ScEnc2EncID "103" .  }
}
```

**And is then expanded like this**

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  obo:  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

INSERT {
  GRAPH turbo:expanded_encounters {
    ?NewEnc rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 .
    ?NewEnc turbo:previousUriText ?previousUriText .
    ?NewEnc obo:OBI_0000299 ?DiagCrid .
    ?DiagCrid rdf:type turbo:DiagCrid .
    ?DiagCrid obo:BFO_0000051 ?DiagSymb .
    ?DiagSymb rdf:type turbo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol .
    ?DiagSymb turbo:thingLiteralValue ?DiagSymbVal .
  }
}
WHERE
  { GRAPH turbo:encounters_from_karma
      { ?EncFromKarma
                  rdf:type              obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
                  turbo:ScEnc2DiagCode  ?DiagSymbVal
        BIND(str(?EncFromKarma) AS ?previousUriText)
        BIND(uri(concat("http://transformunify.org/ontologies/", struuid())) AS ?NewEnc)
        BIND(uri(concat("http://transformunify.org/ontologies/", struuid())) AS ?DiagCrid)
        BIND(uri(concat("http://transformunify.org/ontologies/", struuid())) AS ?DiagSymb)
      }
  }
```

**And therefore looks like this:**

```
@prefix turbo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/> .
@prefix obo: <http://example.org/ontologies/> .

<http://example.org/ontologies/b9dc5b08-cf1b-465e-8773-4b19bfbcf803>
  a <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OGMS_0000097> ;
  turbo:OBI_0000299 <http://example.org/ontologies/8a04f52f-22d2-4aab-bacf-d96e1c7fe900> ;
  obo:previousUriText "http://example.org/ontologies/5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1" .

obo:8a04f52f-22d2-4aab-bacf-d96e1c7fe900
  a obo:DiagCrid ;
  turbo:BFO_0000051 obo:6738d8c0-8bb8-4078-8430-5e9294e5af15 .

obo:6738d8c0-8bb8-4078-8430-5e9294e5af15
  a obo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol ;
  obo:thingLiteralValue "J44.9" .

obo:d3a8a700-2eb9-420d-a863-d47462fa393c
  a turbo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  turbo:OBI_0000299 obo:c12acc26-6dbe-486d-9ae9-9f34c9561aea ;
  obo:previousUriText "http://example.org/ontologies/81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7" .

obo:c12acc26-6dbe-486d-9ae9-9f34c9561aea
  a obo:DiagCrid ;
  turbo:BFO_0000051 obo:3b784151-b369-4594-9ce3-285f5fe60850 .

obo:3b784151-b369-4594-9ce3-285f5fe60850
  a obo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol ;
  obo:thingLiteralValue "I50.9" .

obo:af0e949a-99e4-48cd-885b-7cb1aa3dd265
  a turbo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  turbo:OBI_0000299 obo:c2da52ec-7331-4011-b8f8-6fbf8b419708 ;
  obo:previousUriText "http://example.org/ontologies/820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f" .

obo:c2da52ec-7331-4011-b8f8-6fbf8b419708
  a obo:DiagCrid ;
  turbo:BFO_0000051 obo:7f8399ef-5fcd-447c-80a4-18dfb160e99c .

obo:7f8399ef-5fcd-447c-80a4-18dfb160e99c
  a obo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol ;
  obo:thingLiteralValue "602.9" .
```

**Finally, I can check for the correct transformation with the suggestions from @Joshua Taylor or @AKSW:**

***@Joshua Taylor***

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  obo:  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

ASK
WHERE
  { { GRAPH turbo:expanded_encounters
        { VALUES ( ?previousUriTextVal ?DiagSymbVal ) {
            ( "http://example.org/ontologies/5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1" "J44.9" )
            ( "http://example.org/ontologies/820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f" "602.9" )
            ( "http://example.org/ontologies/81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7" "I50.9" )
          }
          FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?NewEnc   rdf:type              obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
                                        turbo:previousUriText  ?previousUriTextVal ;
                                        obo:OBI_0000299       ?DiagCrid .
                              ?DiagCrid  rdf:type             turbo:DiagCrid ;
                                        obo:BFO_0000051       ?DiagSymb .
                              ?DiagSymb  rdf:type             turbo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol ;
                                        turbo:thingLiteralValue  ?DiagSymbVal
                            }
        }
    }
  }
```

***@AKSW***

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  obo:  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

ASK
WHERE
  { GRAPH turbo:expanded_encounters
      { FILTER ( ?count = 3 )
        { SELECT  (COUNT(DISTINCT ?NewEnc) AS ?count)
          WHERE
            { VALUES ( ?previousUriTextVal ?DiagSymbVal ) {
                ( "http://example.org/ontologies/5f62d61cee174283a4f875ccb8bb91a1" "J44.9" )
                ( "http://example.org/ontologies/820dd597229244ab853ed845dd740f1f" "602.9" )
                ( "http://example.org/ontologies/81fcbb5c5bd141c9bde7f23321648ff7" "I50.9" )
              }
              ?NewEnc   rdf:type              obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
                        turbo:previousUriText  ?previousUriTextVal ;
                        obo:OBI_0000299       ?DiagCrid .
              ?DiagCrid  rdf:type             turbo:DiagCrid ;
                        obo:BFO_0000051       ?DiagSymb .
              ?DiagSymb  rdf:type             turbo:EncounterDiagCodeSymbol ;
                        turbo:thingLiteralValue  ?DiagSymbVal
            }
        }
      }
  }
```